# I am integrating google classroom and want to know that how many records classroom api returns at a time?

Tags: google-classroom

Maximum number of records does google api return at a time.Should i need to implement pagination service to pass page size or it can return any number of courses/teachers/students

Comment: AFAIK, there is no documentation about the maximum number of records the Classroom API can return. But as you can see in this [document](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list) (students.list method), there is a parameter `pageSize` to set the maximum number of items to return. Take note that the server may return fewer than the specified number of results. Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably not directly related to the Classroom API, but I'm partial to using the Admin SDK as a reference (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) - it states that the `maxResults` field has a maximum value of 500.